# Error using ExportAsFixedFormat command

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to debug some code containing an ExportAsFixedFormat that is causing an "Automation error the object invoked has disconnected from its clients." error message. I am running in 2013 so don't need the PDF/XPS add-in and the function works elsewhere in the workbook. It seems to have something to do with the page I am trying to make the PDF out of. While the main macro is longer, I am having the same error occur when I use this simple piece of code:

```
Sub NewAssetScreen()

    Sheets("New Asset").Select
    Sheets("New Asset").Activate

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                   IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

    Sheets("New Asset").Select
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

However if I run the macro with a different worksheet name it works fine. The selection part seems to be ok - ie will work with that worksheet name but it is just the ExportAsFixedFormat command that won't work on the page.

Any insights as to why this might be the case?

Thanks in advance.

Nic

Comment: Anything embedded in the problem sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Check page breaks and other things specific to that worksheet.
Try using `Sheets("New Asset").ExportAsFixedFormat` instead of `ActiveSheet`.
Lastly try copying and pasting the contents of the New Asset sheet to a new sheet and delete the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no "/" or other non file name characters in any of the worksheet fields you are using. My issue occured when printing 100 worksheets, 2 would fail. After much frustration I found the "/" in a heading I was using for the name the file :)