# ExportAsFixedFormat PDF stopped office 365

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, export

I am a basic user.  I generally piece my VBA code together from google searches and stackoverflow advice.  I had a workbook using `"ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF"`. I had 4 lines of code that saved various pages of a worksheet to PDFs on my local hard drive.  Since I got a new computer (and maybe since I updgraded to Office 365) my macro has been returning this error:

> Runtime Error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
>
> Automation Error
>
> The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

Here is the code as I have it now...

```
Sub Savepdf()

Worksheets("Weekly").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\Users\directoryhere\pc2018summer.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, From:=1, To:=10
Worksheets("Weekly").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\Users\directoryhere\pc2018fall.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, From:=11, To:=25
Worksheets("Weekly").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\Users\directoryhere\pc2018winter.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, From:=28, To:=42
Worksheets("Weekly").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\Users\directoryhere\pc2018.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Long shot, but check the value in Options->Advanced->Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)

Comment: Similar (no answer though...) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26009259/error-using-exportasfixedformat-command